# Check whether request is WP REST API request?

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

What is the best way to check whether a request is an API request?

Note that the request might be a custom API request, which means it may be as follows:

```
mysite.com/wp-json/my_namespace/my_version/my_action
```

Obviously, I can check whether the API route wp-json, but there should be a built-in function to check that.

I need it to do some hooks such as

```
add_action('init', 'do_something_only_if_api_request');

function do_something_only_if_api_request()
{
   if ( ! wp_api_request() ) {
     return;
   }
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can check `defined('REST_REQUEST')`. This constant is defined as `true` in `rest_api_loaded()` (and not defined otherwise).

There was a [discussion of WP Rest API developers](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/926) about the introduction of a new function like `is_rest_request()`. In the end they went for this constant.

Comment: Note that `REST_REQUEST` is only defined during the "wp" action (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), which is much later than the "init" action.

Comment: Not sure if it's changed since this last comment but I was trying to find where `REST_REQUEST` was first defined and it looks like it's now in the `parse_request` action

Answer (score 2):

As of December 2016, the REST API documentation is pretty poor regarding everything which doesn't look like an endpoint.

However, a few functions exist and you can find the documentation right in the file as they're very well documented, see: `wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api.php`

If you want add an action only on an REST API call then you probably want to hook the action: `rest_api_init`, it would look like:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'do_something_only_if_api_request');

function do_something_only_if_api_request($wp_rest_server)
{

   // do stuff

}
```

You can find the details in the PHPdoc comment:

```
    /**
     * Fires when preparing to serve an API request.
     *
     * Endpoint objects should be created and register their hooks on this action rather
     * than another action to ensure they're only loaded when needed.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Server $wp_rest_server Server object.
     */
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the plugin is doing wp_redirect for users to login page.

I want to avoid this in case that the rest api is called.

So I'm using

```
if (! strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-json')) // It's not a rest-api call
```

Comment: What if a page/post URL literally has `wp-json` in it?

Comment: I would check for `REST_REQUEST` first, but in case you need to check before that gets defined, perhaps something like ```if (strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-json') == 1) // It is most-likely a rest request```

Comment: This is better approach: if (strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-json/') !== 0). The suggested answer will be passed if URL has wp-json inside it e.g. example.com/all-about-wp-json/